# Unity generic overload of Resolve

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

When I look at version 3.0 of `IUnityContainer` it only has:

```
object Resolve(Type t, string name, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
```

Where do I find the generic version so I can do:

```
container.Reslove < IDoStuff>()
```

Latest version on *nuget* hasn't got it or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IUnityContainer.Resolve<T>()` is an extension method. Add

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
```

to the source file where you want to call `Resolve<T>()`